# Proof that a function is integrable

Tags: integration

If I want to prove that a function $f$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R}$ is it sufficient to just carry out the integration and show the result is finite, i.e. $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \, dx<\infty$, or must I show that it conforms with the definition of integrability, i.e. $\int_{-\infty}^\infty|f(x)| \, dx<\infty$? The reason I ask is that the former is easier to calculate than the latter in the particular case I am considering.

Thanks...

Comment: In what sense are you discussing the integral? Note that (improper) Riemann integrals can exist in cases when Lebesgue integrals do not.

Comment: In this case an a Riemann integral. There is nothing fancy or pathological about f.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you don't know the integrability of a function $f$, how can you directly integrate it? A sufficient and necessary condition of a function to be integrated is that the function shall be bounded and continuous almost everywhere.

But if you mean whether the integration is convergent. Then the former criteria is called conditional convergence and the latter absolute convergence and you should specify in detailed case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Shuchang. I can directly integrate because I can calculate the anti derivative, feed the limits in and obtain a finite result.

Comment: So now, is your question still unsolved?

Comment: Not quite @Shuchang. Must I also show that f is absolutely integrable? It seems to me that this would be a superfluous step, but hey, that's what the definition of integrability requires.

Comment: I know what you mean. Indeed in some place absolutely integrable is required. Then you must follow the definition. There are a large class of functions that are conditional integrable but absolutely integrable. Take a simple example, $\int\arctan x$ is zero but $\int|\arctan x|$ is infinity